# Is this question too narrow for Workplace?

Tags: discussion

To me, this seems too narrow, and focuses solely on an individual's specific case, to be viable for Workplace:

[Advice on how to manage a side project that a separate company wants to use?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17980/advice-on-how-to-manage-a-side-project-that-a-separate-company-wants-to-use)

Anyone disagree?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely convinced the question is on topic on The Workplace. The question is coming from someone who is dealing with an external entity, not a member of his workplace.

Also, the question is about how to protect intellectual property and what ways the developer could profit from the work he's done.  It sounds like this question would be a better fit at [Freelancing SE](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com).

I've considered migrating the question or Freelancing SE, but since it's already been migrated once, has no close votes, and has an answer, I'm wondering, what makes this a Workplace SE question?

To answer your question, I don't see it as being too narrow, just not really a question about the workplace. Stack Exchange focused on solving long tail problems, the kind that you may not find searching articles, blogs, and other generalized resources. However, it could probably be edited a bit to use more of an active voice. It seems like the author is "thinking out loud" in the post. I don't think that makes it closeable, but such edits would make it feel more like what we are used to seeing in Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: I don't think it is off topic... but I do not think it is a great question either.  I agree it fits freelancing better.  I think it should not have been migrated here though in its current form.

Comment: Maybe we could migrate a few of the crap questions we have gotten recently to programmers just to get even?